# Index rebuild of system-versioned table

Tags: sql-server

Curious, if a table is system-versioned and an index needs to be reorganized/rebuilt, how will its history table affect this operation. Does the history table have to get checked/scanned during an index rebuild on the main table?

Comment: I would speculate that from an index maintenance standpoint, the history table is managed separately since IIRC it can be indexed in a completely different way than the parent table. As such, there isn't necessarily an analogous index to maintain. That said, I'd just try it (in a test environment if you're concerned) and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do index maintenance on an index in SQL Server, the history table of a system-versioned table will not be affected by this operation. The history table is a separate and independent table. The history table will not be scanned at all.